# Who are Mrs. Fuji and Mrs. Gas?

Tags: honorifics, suffixes

Is there any etymological relationship between the -さん suffix in 富士山 or 月山 and the -さん suffix you put at the end of a person's name? Or are they unrelated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Totally unrelated.
山 さん [mountain] is a Chinese word "shān" assimilated in Japanese.
さん as a honorific suffix is an old さま undergone some phonetical change.
There are many homophones in Japanese besides that.